# Why was Boromir sent alone to Rivendell?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

Boromir was the first son of the Steward of Gondor and a captain of Gondor. Yet, he was sent without escort North-West with only his horse, shield, sword, and horn to investigate Faramir's dream. Why didn't Denethor send some soldiers with him, or perhaps a guide? The chances of him being injured, lost, or waylaid seemed pretty high given that he didn't even know where Rivendell was.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The only indication we get for why he went alone is because the way was

### *"full of doubt and danger..."*

Boromir wouldn't allow his brother to go, because of the above fears, and decided he would go himself. His father likely demanded he take people with him but Boromir would've had the same fears for them as he did for his brother.

> Therefore  my brother, seeing how desperate was our need, **was eager to heed the dream and seek for Imladris; but since the way was full of doubt and danger, I took the journey  upon  myself.**  Loth  was  my  father  to  give  me  leave,  and  long  have  I wandered by roads forgotten, seeking the house of Elrond, of which many had heard, but few knew where it lay.’
> <sub>Fellowship of the Ring - Book II, Chapter 2: The Council of Elrond</sub>

Another reason, may be because the people of Gondor expected no dangers to their West. As Boromir says, they've protected the West from the dangers to the East.

> By our valour the wild folk of the East are  still  restrained,  and  the  terror  of  Morgul  kept  at  bay;  and  thus  alone  are peace  and freedom  maintained in  the  lands  behind  us, bulwark  of  the  West.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Denethor and Boromir likely would not have feared what lay West given the horrors they faced to the East.

Boromir described the lands to the West as being protected and "behind" the fighting:

> But  still  we  fight  on,  holding  all  the  west  shores  of  Anduin;  and  those  who **shelter behind us give us praise**, if ever they hear our name: much praise but little help. Only from Rohan now will any men ride to us when we call.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

---

There is but one note made about the journey outside of the trilogy and it reinforces the bravery of Boromir to travel on his own. This, in my opinion, strengthens the idea that Boromir did not care to put other people at risk but himself, knowing the effect their losses would be on the wars to come.

> When Boromir made his great journey from Gondor to Rivendell — the courage and hardihood required is not fully recognized in the narrative — the North-South Road no longer existed except for the crumbling remains of the causeways, by which a hazardous approach to Tharbad might be achieved, only to find ruins on dwindling mounds, and a dangerous ford formed by the ruins of the bridge, impassable if the river had not been there slow and shallow — but wide.
> <sub>Unfinished Tales, Part 2, Chapter 4, Appendix D, The History of Galadriel and Celeborn: The Port of Lond Daer</sub>

Comment: Pretty weird though, given what we know of Denethor and the fact that Boromir is his heir. It probably also speaks to how badly things had degenerated in the West  and Gondor that they didn't even know where Rivendell was. Like I imagine it almost post-apocalyptic.

Comment: @just_happen_to_know post apocalyptic tends to imply some mass destruction. But I doubt it was anything that bad. From the final quote it seems more like the elves had begun to keep of themselves, trade with the Dwarves stopped after the fall of Moria and the roads were neglected. This made the passage difficult to follow. Rivendell was also hidden unless you knew the way into the Valley. I also reckon there was a level of secrecy required and hence why Boromir went alone, but I haven’t had time to revisit the answer yet

Comment: I was thinking of the destruction of Arnor (or whatever successor states were left) by Angmar. Seems like the Arnorians were reduced to quasi-nomadic bands of Dunedain.

Comment: +1 for the first quote. I think the fact that Denethor didn't want him to go, shows everything we wanted to know.  Maybe Denny did want to send guards, but B was gonna do what B was gonna do. I would guess that the old man was secretly pleased/proud of his favored son for taking on the dangerous mission on his own.

Comment: There's another part to the answer: he wasn't actually at as much risk when he parted. A Journey in the Dark of Book II of The Fellowship: **'Things have changed since you came north, Boromir,' answered Gandalf. 'Did you not hear what I told you of Saruman? With him I may have business of my own ere all is over. But the Ring must not come near Isengard, if that can by any means be prevented. The Gap of Rohan is closed to us while we go with the Bearer.** Now although it might be specifically for that part the fact remains things were different.

Comment: And yet another part to the answer: Gondor is facing a very serious threat, and Boromir says they lack men already. Under those circumstances, how many skilled warriors can Gondor spare on this weird quest?

Comment: There's also Faramir's take on the matter (Book four) _"Alas that ever he went on that errand! I should have been chosen by my father and the elders but he put himself forward, as being the older and the hardier (both true), and he would not be stayed."_ During Denethor's discussion with Gandalf, Faramir (and Pippin), Denethor also implies he chose Boromir to go. The absense of escort is probably explained by the fact that west was considered relatively safe as Rohan was an ally and Saruman's treachery had not been discovered.

Comment: @just_happen_to_know We know elves are masters of concealment (cf. the elvish cloaks). Elrond was the great-great-grandson of Melian the Maia, a divine being who used *her* magic to conceal the realm of Doriath for thousands of years, and he also had the Ring of Air. Seems pretty likely that the uncertainty about Rivendell was due to magical protection by Elrond, rather than bad record-keeping in Gondor.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent I buy that elves are good at concealment, but I don't think Elrond ever displayed stunts on the level of the Girdle of Melian. Seems like most people in the North were able to find Rivendell easily enough (even the Nazgul). If anyone could pull off something on that scale you'd think it would be Galadriel who seems to be the most powerful of the elves while Elrond seems to be mostly a healer, loremaster, and river guy.

Comment: @Edlothiad I just realized it's kind of a paradox isn't it? The journey is dangerous enough for Boromir to insist that he go alone, but the lands behind Gondor are safe so they don't expect any danger?

Comment: @just_happen_to_know The Nazgûl you mean. But you here also don't understand. The Ring draws them in. They are entirely irrelevant as an example of 'finding Rivendell'. Even so I fail to see how it would be down to bad record keeping; if it wasn't for Gondor's record keeping Gandalf wouldn't have known what the final test would be. And again the journey wasn't as dangerous as it became when he finally arrived; **[...]a hundred and ten days I have journeyed all alone.[...]** That's 110 days. A lot can happen in that time esp when you had both Saruman and Sauron to deal with.

Comment: @just_happen_to_know If I recall correctly, Galadriel *does* pull off something of that scale. I think there's a statement somewhere that only Sauron in his full power could pierce the defences of Lorien.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Yes. Lothlórien would only be breached if Sauron himself were to come.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Good catch, that is a stunt probably on the scale of Melian.